# unable to increase speed of the bot using dwa_local_parameter

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to increase the speed of skid steering bot using dwa local planner but the speed doesn't increase above 0.5.
I have tried manipulating acceleration, velocity and translational limit in the parameter file but the result is still the same.
I don't get what is limiting the bot to not increase the speed above 0.5 m/s.

> Update-
> I checked the situation using `rqt_reconfigure` and the bot is able to react to any value in `max_vel_x` throughout the slider. But when I mention the same values in the yaml file, the bot sticks to 0.5 m/s for vel > 0.5.

Below is the content of my `dwa_local_planner_params.yaml` file-

```
DWAPlannerROS:

  max_vel_x: 1.5  
  min_vel_x: 0.0 

  max_vel_y: 0.0  
  min_vel_y: 0.0  

  max_trans_vel: 1.5
  min_trans_vel: 0.0  
  trans_stopped_vel: 0.1

  max_rot_vel: 5.0  
  min_rot_vel: 0.4  
  rot_stopped_vel: 0.4
  
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_theta: 2.0
  acc_lim_y: 2.5

  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.3  
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.5 

  sim_time: 1.0       
  vx_samples: 6        
  vy_samples: 1      
  vtheta_samples: 20  

  path_distance_bias: 90.0      
  goal_distance_bias: 24.0      
  occdist_scale: 0.50           
  forward_point_distance: 0.325 
  stop_time_buffer: 0.2         
  scaling_speed: 0.25           
  max_scaling_factor: 0.2      

  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05  

  publish_traj_pc : true
  publish_cost_grid_pc: true
  global_frame_id: odom
```

Launch File-

```
<node pkg="agv_navigation" name="controller" type="goal_sequence.py"></node>

<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"/> 
<param name ="publish_frequency" type=" double" value="50.0"/>

<arg name="map_file" value="$(find agv_navigation)/map/world.yaml"/>

<node pkg="map_server" type="map_server" name="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" output = "screen" />

<include file="$(find agv_navigation)/launch/amcl.launch" />
<include file="$(find agv_description)/launch/agv_visualize.launch"/>

<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
  <param name="base_local_planner" value="dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS"/>

<rosparam file="$(find agv_navigation)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find agv_navigation)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find agv_navigation)/config/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find agv_navigation)/config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find agv_navigation)/config/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
<rosparam file="$(find agv_navigation)/config/move_base_params.yaml" command="load"/>
<rosparam file="$(find agv_navigation)/config/dwa_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load"/>
<rosparam file="$(find agv_navigation)/config/global_planner.yaml" command="load"/>
<remap from="cmd_vel" to="/cmd_vel"/>
<remap from="odom" to="odom"/>

</node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365824/unable-to-increase-speed-of-the-bot-using-dwa_local_parameter/) by [arjunchatterg](https://answers.ros.org/users/63547/arjunchatterg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2020-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-11-18**:
Please use proper tags. `gmapping` and `djikstra` have nothing to do with your question. Thanks.

Did you observe `move_base` actually publishing only a maximum velocity of 0.5m/s? Might be something else is limiting the robots velocity as well.
Also, please check that the parameters are actually used, i.e. they are loaded in the correct namespace.

**Comment by [arjunchatterg](https://answers.ros.org/users/63547/arjunchatterg/) on 2020-11-18**:\

1. /cmd_vel topic echoes the mentioned speed.
2. What parameter could limit the speed ? Local planner should only be responsible for robot's speed right ?
3. How do I check if they are correctly loaded ? rqt_graph seems fine to me.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-11-18**:
`max_vel_x` and `max_vel_trans` should be the relevant ones.
Does changing any parmeter have any effect on the robot? Try setting it to 0.1m/s and see if it is observing this limit. If not, you probably have loaded the parameters in the wrong namespace.
Edit your question and show the launch file with which you upload the parameters.

**Comment by [arjunchatterg](https://answers.ros.org/users/63547/arjunchatterg/) on 2020-11-18**:
Bot is reacting to speed less than 0.5 m/s. But it stays at 0.5-0.55 even if I provide 1.0 m/s.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-11-18**:
is this stuff on a repo that we can check? I don't see anything wrong with the configuration, but there are so many things to check that having this on a repo would really help...

**Comment by [arjunchatterg](https://answers.ros.org/users/63547/arjunchatterg/) on 2020-11-18**:\

1. Config files are slight modifications of this [repo](https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros/tree/master/chapter_4_codes/diff_wheeled_robot_gazebo/param)
2. Python script contains a simple addition of a loop of waypoints in this [code](https://hotblackrobotics.github.io/en/blog/2018/01/29/action-client-py/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out the solution.
The parameter is actually `max_vel_trans` instead of `max_trans_vel`.

Thanks for your concern.

---

Originally posted by [arjunchatterg](https://answers.ros.org/users/63547/arjunchatterg/) with karma: 36 on 2020-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-11-19**:
great you figured it out. Actually, the parameter name has been changed in melodic. Also, the planner outputs [a warning](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/dwa_local_planner/src/dwa_planner_ros.cpp#L126-L131) ([see also this](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/nav_core/include/nav_core/parameter_magic.h#L71-L82)) which you should have seen.
But I also missed the name change :-D

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2020-11-19**:
Congratulations.

**Comment by [arjunchatterg](https://answers.ros.org/users/63547/arjunchatterg/) on 2020-11-19**:
Yes, I figured out after I looked at the warning.
Thank you so much for your time and concern @mgruhler and @miura